# Angular Gulp setup with latest NodeJS version

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp

I have been following the repo [A healthy Gulp Setup](https://github.com/paislee/healthy-gulp-angular) for the gulp setup of my AngularJS project.

I can successfully proceed with this in an older version of nodejs. But on my another system, I have installed a newer version "**NodeJS 4.2.2**" and I get many dependency errors.

At initial try of `npm install` I got the error

```
npm WARN engine karma@0.10.10: wanted: {"node":"~0.8 || ~0.10"} (current: {"node
":"4.2.2","npm":"2.14.7"})
```

I tried modifying the karma version in package.json from **0.10 to 0.13**. This time the npm install hangs for hours while processing bufferutil.

```
C:\wamp\www\ros_ui\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket
.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_mo
dules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
 )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
  bufferutil.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.c
     Creating library C:\wamp\www\ros_ui\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket
  .io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\
  ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\Release\bufferutil.lib and object C:\wamp\ww
  w\ros_ui\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-cli
  ent\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\bui
  ld\Release\bufferutil.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  bufferutil.vcxproj -> C:\wamp\www\ros_ui\node_modules\karma\node_modules\sock
  et.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_module
  s\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\Release\\bufferutil.node
```

Is there any work around for this? I would prefer going with latest node version.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [angularcoffee-boilerplate](https://github.com/alexandervantrijffel/angularcoffee-boilerplate), this is a project template for AngularJS where npm and Gulp are preconfigured. Just clone the project, install prerequisites with the script `install_prerequisites.bat` and start the server with the command `npm start`